# set the same palette for multiple charts in subplot

Tags: charts, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python, subplot

I want to have 4 charts on a subplot with similar colourings, as the bars are representing the same value. However, the output is giving different colour schemes. What can I do to fix it?

The code:

```
import plotly
# Creating subplot
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, shared_yaxes=True)

cols = plotly.colors.DEFAULT_PLOTLY_COLORS

# Adding charts
fig.add_trace(fig1['data'][0], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(fig1['data'][1], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(fig1['data'][2], row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(fig2['data'][0], row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(fig2['data'][1], row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(fig2['data'][2], row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(fig3['data'][0], row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(fig3['data'][1], row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(fig3['data'][2], row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(fig4['data'][0], row=2, col=2)
fig.add_trace(fig4['data'][1], row=2, col=2)
fig.add_trace(fig4['data'][2], row=2, col=2)
```

Colour schemes are too different and not representing similar values

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zxz4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify colours when you plot a bar chart.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Bar( x = df.iloc[:,1], y = df.iloc[:,2], marker_color='black'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar( x = df.iloc[:,1], y = df.iloc[:,2], marker_color='red'), row=1, col=1)
```

Alternatively, you can update traces in the end.

```
color_list = [col1, col2, col3,...col9]
for idx, d in enumerate(fig.data):
    d.marker.color = color_list[idx]
```